# Split a string within a list python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I have a list in python, which is from a text document that I split at new line characters. The end of data is indicated with `#` in the text document. I need to count each of element of the list and then split the strings in the list at tab characters, creating a two dimensional list.

I thought this was fairly simple, however, I'm not getting a result from my code. The strings in the list are not splitting at all, nevermind at `\t`.

```
with open('names.txt') as names:
    records = names.read().split('\n')
recordcount = 0
for item in records:
    if item != '#':
        recordcount += 1
        item = item.split('\t')
print (records)
print (recordcount)
```

Has this got something to do with tab characters being troublesome? Or can I not replace elements of a list in-place? Should I be creating a new list with my split records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just reassigning a local variable. This doesn't affect the contents of the list. Try this:

```
for i, item in enumerate(records):
    if item != '#':
        recordcount += 1
        records[i] = item.split('\t')
```

Comment: Ohh, yes of course, that was obvious actually. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can replace list items in-place, but `item = item.split('\t')` just re-assigns the local variable `item`.  You can easily replace the list item by e.g. `records[index] = item`.  You can get the right `index` by using the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function.

Your code changed to do what you want:

```
with open('names.txt') as names:                                            
    records = names.read().split('\n')                                      
recordcount = 0                                                             
for index, item in enumerate(records):                                      
    if item != '#':                                                         
        recordcount += 1                                                    
        item = item.split('\t')                                             
        records[index] = item                                               
print (records)                                                             
print (recordcount)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I should have looked more closely at my work, such an obvious error. Thanks.